# Can I connect multiple computers with PCIe?

Tags: pcie

I've got an crazy idea about obtaining some **Computer on Module** boards having PCIe connection. Putting them in **PCIe network**, not ethernet network.

Is it possible to connect multiple computers / CoMs together with PCIe (switch)? And some custom made drivers for transporting data.

edit: Will it go flawlessly without main computer/device that will control the network?

Answer (score 1):

Since PCIe is just a serial point to point link, is encapsulated in SATA (which includes eSATA - for external use) and has support in the standard for I/O virtualization I'd say "yes".  In fact that is one of it's intended purposes.

Comment: OK, does that mean, that I can use it as direct conection without PC -> SATA -> cable -> SATA -> PC?

And is SATA capable of network connections, like PCIe? Instead of point-to-point?

Comment: External connections must take into account mechanical and ESD and grounding considerations like eSATA.  So a PCIe for external use must also.  Whether or not it looks like a network connection is entirely a software/driver/kernel module issue.  You can support a direct connection between machines, _how_ it is used is another matter entirely.

Comment: I didn't say, thet It will be external connection. I plan to put them together on one board. I now know, what I really meant by question: Can I connect... -> will it go without main computer, or does PCIe need some main computer/chip to controll it?

Comment: It won't magically connect and look like a ethernet connection.  There is link signalling and control, register settings, data flow support (DMA etc.) so yes, it will require controlling.

Comment: @Miro - And control includes "a lot of stuff" that takes a whole lot of experience with PCIe hardware layer protocol, signal integrity issues, PCIe flow control issues for reset, power up, power down, lane training, etc etc etc. And with all that the PCIe lanes are still point to single point and not daisy chainable as a buss oriented connection as your original question seems to ask.

Comment: I think you will need a root complex as part of your setup but that doesn't mean all traffic has to go through it.   If you made a board where one of your modules was the root and connected it to the switch.  Then connect all other modules as end points on the switch.  Now your root should be able to configure everyone and share addresses of other endpoints.   Then I think you can dma between all cards to your hearts content. The data should go through the switch point to point so whatever his bandwidth is will be your bottle neck. You'll have to write some code for all that though.